# apa7 and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa7

I have a problem with the `apa7` and `biblatex` packages and the bibliography section. I'm writing in Spanish, so I put the line `\setcounter{smartand}{1}` to avoid the "&" symbol in documents with 3+ authors. But while the cites looks fine in the text (with "e" or "y" depending the context), in the bibliography section the symbol "&" continues to appear. How can I avoid the use of that symbol in the reference section?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Could you edit your question to include a minimal document that shows what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` has a special name delimiter macro (`name:delim:apa:family-given`) that needs to be redefined if you want to use `smartand`. Due to the way `smartand` is reset by `biblatex-apa` we also need two additional lines of code in `\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}`.

Together we get

```
\documentclass[spanish]{apa7}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \setcounter{smartand}{1}%
  \let\lbx@finalnamedelim=\lbx@es@smartand
  \let\lbx@finallistdelim=\lbx@es@smartand
}

\renewbibmacro*{name:delim:apa:family-given}[1]{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
       or
       test \ifmorenames
     }
       {\printdelim{multinamedelim}}
       {\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby and Humphrey Appleby and Humphrey Ippleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,companion,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Appleby y col., 1980; Goossens y col., 1994; Sigfridsson y Ryde, 1998)//Appleby, H., Appleby, H. e Ippleby, H. (1980).//Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F. y Samarin, A. (1994).]

Comment: It works! Thanks you, this thing made me mad yesterday.

Comment: @Alcarendor Well, `biblatex-apa` implements all idiosyncrasies of APA style as closely as possible, so it can be harder to modify if you want something that is not APA style.